# ReactJs, Losing child component local state on global state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm not understanding some ReactJs behavior and would need some help.

I have a Root Functional Component ("Index"), that contains another functional Component ("Preview").
That Preview component contains several other Functional Components ("InlineField").

The app is a simple form, where InlineField is component that renders an input and also contains a state to know if the field is "opened" or "closed" (when close it is displayed as a text, when open it is displayed as an input).

The global state is defined using hooks ad the "Index" level and moved down to the field through props (I've tried the same using Context). This state contains all form values.

The InlineField Component uses hook to maintain its local state only (is open / is closed).
When a an input is changed it updates the state (Index level) which triggers a re-render of the Index as well as its children.
This translate into the currently edited field (InlineField Component with local state = open) to refresh and lose its state value.

**My question:**
How can I make sure these InlineField Components retain their state even after updating global state?
I could simply move that InlineField Component state to the global state too, but I don't think it makes much sense.

I must be getting something wrong...

Thanks!

---

**Edit: added code sample**

Index Component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"

import Layout from "../components/layout"


const IndexPage = () => {


  const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState({
    name: 'Myname',
    email: 'myemail@mail.com',
  })

  const onFormValueChange = (key, value) => {
    setFormValues({...formValues, [key]: value})
  }

  return (
    <Layout>
      <Preview
        key="previewyaknow"
        formValues={formValues}
        onFieldChange={setFormValues}
      />
    </Layout>
  )
}
export default IndexPage
```

Preview Component:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Box, TextField } from "@material-ui/core"
import { InlineField } from './inlineField'

export const Preview = ({formValues, onFieldChange}) => {

  return (
    <>
      <Box display="flex" alignItems="center">
        <InlineField 
          value={formValues.email}
          onChange={onFormValueChange}
          id="email"
          field={<TextField value={formValues.email}/>>>}
        />
    </>
  )
}
```

InlineEdit Component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"

export const InlineField = ({onChange, value, id, field}) => {
  const [isEdit, setIsEdit] = useState(false)

  const onBlur = (e) => {
    setIsEdit(false)
  }

  let view = (<div>{value}</div>);
  if (isEdit) { 
    view = (
      <FieldContainer className={classes.fieldContainer}>
        {React.cloneElement(field, { 
          'onBlur': onBlur, 
          'autoFocus': true, 
          'onChange': (e) => {
            onChange(id, e.target.value) 
          }
        })
        }
      </FieldContainer>
    )
  }

  return (
    <div onClick={()=>setIsEdit(!isEdit)}>
      {view}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the code where you are passing down the state down?

Comment: It's hard to tell why this happens without some code to look at, but it shouldn't happen. It sounds like your issue is related to the InlineField component being re-instantiated, rather than just re-rendered. Again though, please provide some code in your question.

Comment: @Chris My thought exactly, why would state revert when you just updated it?

Comment: I've added code sample. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: I'm not sure why you are using `cloneElement` here but I believe your problem is related to that since you are calling it inside your `render` method, it will yield a new instance of `field` each time. I haven't used it in ages, so I might be wrong...

Comment: I use this to add properties to a component passed in props. I've just tested it by replacing this line with a simple input and a onChange attribute, and the problem remains the same.

If the value is changed, the local state of the inlineField is lost too.

Comment: @LEM01 check that the `field` component does not unmount when you type. If it is a func component, you can do this by adding a console log to the return of a useEffect. If it logs, it means the component was unmounted.

Comment: @Chris yes it gets unmounted whenever the value changes

Comment: @LEM01 hard to troubleshoot without a working example, but I'm guessing the problem is either with your `cloneElement` or the way you pass `TextField` as a prop. Maybe try converting your `field` prop to be a render prop instead. That way you can pass `formValues` as a func parameter and use that instead of `cloneElement`. I can provide an answer if you want the code for how to do that

Comment: @Chris I'll try to setup a live example. I've changed this part with a simple <input /> that calls onChange. Same story.